# inconsistent css height for element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I have a relatively simple jquery function I am using to set the height of one div, based on the parent height.

```
(function() {
var $window = $(window);
function resize() {
    if ($window.width() > 800) {
        $(".event-list").each(function() {
          var parentHeight =  $(this).height();
          $(this).children('.text').css("height",parentHeight);
          $(this).children('.pattern').css("height",parentHeight);
        });
    } else {
      $(".event-list").each(function() {
        $(this).children('.text').css("height", 'auto');
        $(this).children('.pattern').css("height", 'auto');
     });
    }
}
$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

You can see it working here: http://theadventureschool.com/new-site/events/

On my local computer this works correctly every time, but when I pushed the site live, sometimes the height is the correct value, and sometimes it defaults to 22px.

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jenny

Comment: Does it work after clearing your browser cache?

Comment: The cache doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: It seems to work pretty consistently in Chrome, but not Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the image to finish loading.  If I take the image out and resize the page I get the 22px height.  Try adding in a listener on the image load and once the image is done loading then do the initial sizing.

```
(function() {
var $window = $(window);
$(".event-list img").load(function() {
    resize();
});
function resize() {
    if ($window.width() > 800) {
        $(".event-list").each(function() {
         var parentHeight =  $(this).height();
         $(this).children('.text').css("height",parentHeight);
         $(this).children('.pattern').css("height",parentHeight);
     });
} else {
  $(".event-list").each(function() {
    $(this).children('.text').css("height", 'auto');
    $(this).children('.pattern').css("height", 'auto');
 });
}
}
$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize')
    .load(resize);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That sounds like a perfect solution, unfortunately I am a bit of a beginner in jquery. Can you point me in the right direction for how to add a listener?

Comment: `$('.event-list img').load(function() { code goes here });`

Comment: Like this, right after the $(function()? That doesn't seem to working. I also tried to add it with the resize() function, also didn't work.

Comment: `$(function() {
  $('.event-list img').load(function() {
    var $window = $(window);`

Comment: `$(function() {
$('.event-list img').load(function() { resize(); }
function resize() { resize code}
}`

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm. Really, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() solve this?

JQuery documentation:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I added  
    $(function() {  

 to the function, and it still seems to have the same problem.

Comment: Should this function be included in the header or footer of the page?

Comment: Example:
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  function resize() {
    ...
});